# Convert wide pandas dataframe of daily data by week into long dataframe of daily data

Tags: pandas

I am working with a pandas dataframe where each row includes the start date for the week, and the daily data for that week. For example:

```
    start_date  mon  tue  wed   thu   fri   sat  sun
    2017-01-01  10   15   8     19    20    21   4
```

I would like to do time series analysis and need the data in the following format:

```
    date         amount
    2017-01-01   10
    2017-01-02   15
    2017-01-03   8
    2017-01-04   19
    2017-01-05   20
    2017-01-06   21
    2017-01-07   4
```

I believe I can use pandas melt to convert the dataset from wide to long, but I am struggling with how to best fill in the dates.

I have tried the following approach, but it seems like a work around:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date': {0: '2017-01-01'}, 'mon': {0: 10},
                   'tue': {0: 15}, 'wed': {0: 8}, 'thu': {0: '19'}, 
                   'fri': {0: 20}, 'sat': {0: 21}, 'sun': {0: 4}})

df = df.melt(id_vars='start_date', value_name="amount")

day_add = {'mon': 0,
           'tue': 1,
           'wed': 2,
           'thu': 3,
           'fri': 4,
           'sat': 5,
           'sun': 6,
           }

df = df.replace({"variable": day_add})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], infer_datetime_format=True) + 
             pd.to_timedelta(df['variable'], unit='d')

print(df[['date', 'amount']].sort_values(by=['date']))
```

Results from the current code:

```
        date amount
1 2017-01-01     10
5 2017-01-02     15
6 2017-01-03      8
4 2017-01-04     19
0 2017-01-05     20
2 2017-01-06     21
3 2017-01-07      4
```

Alternative approaches are welcome.

Comment: Your approach seems pretty good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is pretty good. The only thing I'd change (possibly) is substituting the `replace` call with a fast(er) `map` call which you can do in-line.

For completeness, here's a similar solution using `stack`. This is almost the same as using `melt`. I've also showed how I'd use `map` here:

```
u = df.set_index('start_date').stack()
u.index = (
    pd.to_datetime(u.index.get_level_values(0)) 
  + pd.to_timedelta(u.index.get_level_values(1).map(day_add), unit='d'))

u.rename_axis('date').reset_index(name='amount')

        date amount
0 2017-01-01     10
1 2017-01-02     15
2 2017-01-03      8
3 2017-01-04     19
4 2017-01-05     20
5 2017-01-06     21
6 2017-01-07      4
```